# Custom Page instead of "Document Expired" message

Tags: asp.net-core, back-button, asp.net-core-5.0

I am building a asp.net core 5 web app. If a User clicks the back button in the browser the "Document Expired" message shows up (in Firefox). Is it possible to instead show a custom Page or redirect the user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Back button refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189285/back-button-refresh-page)

Comment: thanks @marsh-wiggle. The Post you mention does not answer my question, it is about classic asp.net, I am using asp.net core 5

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) help you?It tells about how to detect Browser Back Button event .